# how to remove localhost from URL in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

the url that I get from API is something like 'https://google.com'
my code in vue is:

`<router-link :to=link class="btn btn-danger m-3 p-3 "> go to link </router-link>`

and data is:

`data(){
      return{
      paylink:'https://google.com'
 }`

but the link that shown me is :'http://localhost:8080/google.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vue-router (and router-link) isintended for local route (to your own domain). For full external URLs just use `<a href="">`

Comment: I dont know what just happened but its worked ... im **surprised** because i think i try this solution anyway thank you :))